# Have motion only save image, not movie

Tags: motion

I'm sure its right there in the config in front of me, I just can't see it.

I am using 'motion' to detect movement and save images. It is also saving .swf files (movies).
How do I disable the saving of a movie? I only want the image snap shots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out the movie saving parts or disable the movie saving parts.
Find the line `ffmpeg_cap_new` and make sure it's either set to `off` or removed altogether

Check the other lines in that area to make sure they are also off / commented out / removed.